# How to upload files?

Tags: fckeditor

I just wanted to know how to configure FCKEditor to upload files and images to the server where the website is hosted.

The relevant part for it's config file(i think) looks like this:

```
FCKConfig.LinkUpload = true ;
FCKConfig.LinkUploadURL = FCKConfig.BasePath + 'filemanager/connectors/' + _QuickUploadLanguage + '/upload.' + _QuickUploadExtension ;
FCKConfig.LinkUploadAllowedExtensions   = ".(7z|aiff|asf|avi|bmp|csv|doc|fla|flv|gif|gz|gzip|jpeg|jpg|mid|mov|mp3|mp4|mpc|mpeg|mpg|ods|odt|pdf|png|ppt|pxd|qt|ram|rar|rm|rmi|rmvb|rtf|sdc|sitd|swf|sxc|sxw|tar|tgz|tif|tiff|txt|vsd|wav|wma|wmv|xls|xml|zip)$" ;            // empty for all
FCKConfig.LinkUploadDeniedExtensions    = "" ;  // empty for no one

FCKConfig.ImageUpload = true ;
FCKConfig.ImageUploadURL = FCKConfig.BasePath + 'filemanager/connectors/' + _QuickUploadLanguage + '/upload.' + _QuickUploadExtension + '?Type=Image' ;
FCKConfig.ImageUploadAllowedExtensions  = ".(jpg|gif|jpeg|png|bmp)$" ;      // empty for all
FCKConfig.ImageUploadDeniedExtensions   = "" ;                          // empty for no one
```

Could it be a folder permission problem? Is this part of the config.js alright?

Comment: What is your problem? What happens when you try to upload a file`? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well, I click the Upload tab, then I pick a file from my pc and then I click the "Upload file to the server" button or something like that, but it doesn't show any message or sign that it has worked. Then, when I check on the server's folder, it's not there.

Comment: Now I get an exception that says "invalid request" when i try to upload a *.doc file. That extension is included on the config file, so i don't know what's wrong. can anybody help me on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved, thanks anyway. I just had to add the "Files" type to some variable at the config.aspx file. It only had "Images", so that's why I couldn't upload files

Answer (score 1):

You don't state what language you are using. The fileupload functionality in FCKeditor has ASP, .NET, Coldfusion and PHP uploaders, amongst others. It would help if you said what server (IIS/Linux?) and serverside language you are using.

With limited information its a long shot but there's settings in **fckconfig.js** for configuring your file browser (around line 276) Make sure you have the right language selected:

```
var _FileBrowserLanguage    = 'php' ;   // asp | aspx | cfm | lasso | perl | php | py
var _QuickUploadLanguage    = 'php' ;   // asp | aspx | cfm | lasso | perl | php | py
```

You'll also have to set write permissions on the folder structure you are uploading to (which might be the cause of the "invalid request" error, but process to edit file permissions is different depending if you are using windows or linux.

Its not well documented, but its also possible to debug the file manager settings by going to the following URLs in a browser:

> /fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/test.html
>
> and
>
> /fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/uploadtest.html

The upload test scripts are very useful and can help diagnose many problems - you can see errors easier for a start. Give them a try and you should have a better idea what the problem is.

Comment: It's solved, thanks anyway. I just had to add the "Files" type to some variable at the config.aspx file. It only had "Images", so that's why I couldn't upload files.